# Add and removing class on jquery

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I am trying to add a class by clicking on specific area and then when i will click on anywhere of body this added class will remove.

I am trying by this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("ul#nav .have_child").removeClass('sub_more');

    $(".have_child").click(function(){
            $(".have_child").addClass('sub_more')
    });
    $("body").click(function(){
            $(".have_child").removeClass('sub_more')
    });


});
```

but it does not work.

My HTML code is

```
<ul id="nav">   
<li class="have_child sub_more">More<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="actualpost.html">actualpost</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I have founded the solution by using this code

```
$(document).(function(){
$("ul#nav .have_child").removeClass('sub_more');

$(".have_child").click(function (ev) {
    $('.have_child').toggleClass('sub_more');
    ev.stopPropagation();
});

$("html").click(function () {
    $(".have_child").removeClass('sub_more')
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that for each click on `.have_child` elements, *two* event handlers are fired: first for `.have_child`, second for `body` (as the event bubbles). While the first handler adds the class, the second one will remove it immediately after.

One obvious solution is to disable event propagation in the first ('deeper') handler:

```
$(".have_child").click(function(ev){
  $(".have_child").addClass('sub_more');
  ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

... so the handler for body click won't be fired.

As a sidenote, it'd really be great to check the accompanying HTML structure: it looks a bit strange that you add the corresponding class to *all* the `.have_child` elements, and not the clicked one only. In other words, this...

```
$(".have_child").click(function(ev){
  $('.have_child').removeClass('sub_more');
  $(this).addClass('sub_more'); 
  ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

... seems more appropriate. Here's a [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/osm1oshr/) showing this approach in action.

Note the (minor) change in that demo: using `$('html')` instead of `$('body')` allows to register clicks on the whole document, not just within the dimensions of `<body>`.

Comment: Thanks, This code added a class but not remove after adding

Comment: Check [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7ysgxw87/), explain what's wrong with it (if anything).

Comment: thanks,

I have use here this cod

$(".have_child").click(function (ev) {
        $('.have_child').toggleClass('sub_more');
        ev.stopPropagation();
    });

    $("html").click(function () {
        $(".have_child").removeClass('sub_more')
    });

and it works as like as i want

Comment: Ah, so you had to 'close' the active item it has been open... Well,  the correct approach would be to toggle the class, then remove the class from the rest of elements - like in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0fewceLk/).

Answer (score 1):

Replace "document" to **[document](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)**,That is not string

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

  ^         ^-----------
```

Comment: I have changed it but it also not working. class is not adding